# Why is $\frac{ r(r+1)\cdots(z+r-1)}{z!} = \binom{z+r-1}{z}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Sorry for this simple question, I am having a bit of trouble understanding how we can know immediately see that the LHS can be written as a binomial coeeficient

Comment: How would you define the RHS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiplying the top and bottom of the LHS by $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots (r-1)$ as follows:

$$ \begin{align}
LHS &=\frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots (r-1)r(r+1)\cdots(z+r-1)}{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots (r-1)z!}\\
&= \frac{(z+r-1)!}{z!(r-1)!} \\
&=\binom{z+r-1}{z}.
\end{align}$$